# Troubleshooting Glue Job Java NullPointer Error

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark, aws-glue

I have the following glue spark job:

```
for x in df.take(65):
    print(x["value"])
    y=x["value"]
    tablename = y
    schema = 'dev'

    dataFrame = spark.read\
        .format("csv")\
        .option("header", "true")\
        .load(f"s3://tempfolder/{tablename}")
    
    gluedf = DynamicFrame.fromDF(dataFrame, glueContext, "glue_df")
    logger.info(f"gluedf loaded for {tablename} with {gluedf.count()} rows")


    postgres_write = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        frame=gluedf,
        connection_type="postgresql",
        connection_options={
            'url':f'jdbc:postgresql://{postgre_db_host}:{postgre_db_port}/{postgre_db_name}',
            'dbtable': f'{schema}.{tablename}',
            "user": postgre_db_username,
            "password": postgre_db_password,
            "database": postgre_db_name
        }
    )
          
    logger.info(f"Data written to postgresql for {tablename} into {schema}.{tablename}")
    
    job.commit()
```

The job is reading files from s3 and write into an aurora postgresql table. From the log, I can see the gluedf has managed to read data from s3 but when writing to postgresql, it failed with `java.lang.NullPointerException` error.

```
23/08/29 01:18:23 ERROR ProcessLauncher: Error from Python:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/my_glue_job.py", line 78, in <module>
    postgres_write = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 642, in from_options
    return self._glue_context.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(frame,
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line 337, in write_dynamic_frame_from_options
    return self.write_from_options(frame, connection_type,
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line 362, in write_from_options
    return sink.write(frame_or_dfc)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awsglue/data_sink.py", line 39, in write
    return self.writeFrame(dynamic_frame_or_dfc, info)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awsglue/data_sink.py", line 32, in writeFrame
    return DynamicFrame(self._jsink.pyWriteDynamicFrame(dynamic_frame._jdf, callsite(), info), dynamic_frame.glue_ctx, dynamic_frame.name + "_errors")
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o114.pyWriteDynamicFrame.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.$anonfun$apply$6(JDBCUtils.scala:996)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues.$anonfun$foreach$3(MapLike.scala:257)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$foreach$1(TraversableLike.scala:985)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:400)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:728)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:984)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues.foreach(MapLike.scala:257)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable.$plus$plus$eq$(Growable.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMapBuilder.$plus$plus$eq(HashMap.scala:1194)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$MapBuilderImpl.$plus$plus$eq(Map.scala:646)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$MapBuilderImpl.$plus$plus$eq(Map.scala:595)
    at scala.collection.immutable.DefaultMap.$plus(DefaultMap.scala:44)
    at scala.collection.immutable.DefaultMap.$plus$(DefaultMap.scala:42)
    at scala.collection.immutable.MapLike$$anon$2.$plus(MapLike.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.immutable.MapLike.$anonfun$$plus$plus$1(MapLike.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$folder$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:196)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$folder$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map3.foreach(Map.scala:376)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:199)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:192)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.foldLeft(Traversable.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$div$colon(TraversableOnce.scala:187)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$div$colon$(TraversableOnce.scala:187)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.$div$colon(Traversable.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.immutable.MapLike.$plus$plus(MapLike.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.immutable.MapLike.$plus$plus$(MapLike.scala:90)
    at scala.collection.immutable.MapLike$$anon$2.$plus$plus(MapLike.scala:105)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.connectionProperties(JDBCUtils.scala:1044)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.connectionProperties$lzycompute(JDBCUtils.scala:820)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.connectionProperties(JDBCUtils.scala:820)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.writeDF(JDBCUtils.scala:969)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.sinks.PostgresDataSink.writeDynamicFrame(PostgresDataSink.scala:42)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DataSink.pyWriteDynamicFrame(DataSink.scala:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I'm new in Glue & spark. The log isn't very helpful in helping troubleshooting. Could anyone advise how to tackle issues like this?